# Possible to generate entity class based on YML file?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to create an entity class based on meta data stored in a YML file. Is this (easily) possible?

I've been digging around the Doctrine library, and found `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator` and `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo`, but I haven't quite figured out how to properly use them, or even if they're they classes I *should* be using.

Some things to consider:

- My YML files are not in a bundle directory
- I can't use the CLI - I need to be able to do this from within a regular PHP class (probably a Symfony2 service)
- I want to store the generated entities in a custom directory (ie: not in a bundle directory)

I thought I'd ask here for advice before I go reinventing too many wheels :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look the EntityGenerator documentation, there's an example there as well:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.Tools.EntityGenerator.html